# How to use GPU on Ubuntu on Virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, gpu, virtualbox, virtualhost

I am running a VM with VirtualBox 6.* on Windows10(host) with Ubuntu (LinuxMint 20, Guest) installed. Is there a way to use my hosts GPU(GTX 1060)?